# How can I divide a C# string into two?

Tags: c#

I would like to output a path:

```
string libraryPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "..", "Library"); // Library folder
Debug.WriteLine((libraryPath));
```

But the path is very long.

How can I output the path in two lines. First 1/2 and then second 1/2 on second line?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of input and expected output

Comment: debug is usually meant for debugging purposes, not to look beautiful. If you want to copy that information at some point you will have to always remember it's on 2 lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [SubString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) to split the output.

```
// Print 1st half (from index 0 to half of length)
Debug.WriteLine((libraryPath.SubString(0, libraryPath.Length / 2)));
// Print 2nd half (from middle of string to end)
Debug.WriteLine((libraryPath.SubString(libraryPath.Length / 2)));
```

*Note: If `Length` is odd, the first half will be shorter.*

Comment: @marsze I don't think you could add more comments if you tried! Well done. Although I did like the self-documenting aspect of the original version. :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the length of the 'library path'
2. Use Substring to split the 'library path' in half
3. Write both halves to variables
4. Write each variable on separate lines

Comment: You could skip 3. , though.

Comment: Yep, you certainly could. I think @marsze summed it up very nicely with his code.